# Change height of bootstrap carousel - keeping it responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented a bootstrap carousel without overriding any styles. I want it to respond the way it does at the moment, so carousel and image respond down together without the image being cropped or distorted - but I would like the starting height of the carousel to be shorter.

It responds like the one on this page:
http://www.suug.co.uk/

So at the moment when the browser is full width it is 650px high, I can see a height attribute hasn't been set, so I am wondering if I can keep the way it responds but change the starting height to say, 550px.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="bannerFrontPage">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item"><a href=""><img src=""></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href=""><img src=""></a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href=""><img src=""></a></div>
        </div>


        <a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" href="#bannerFrontPage"><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a> 
        <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#bannerFrontPage"> <span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution was the following:

```
.carousel img {
    max-height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can also set the max-height to relative measures :)

Comment: Can we use percentage height instead of absolute pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle that may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/gh4Lur4b/140/

You can change the height of your carousel in the class of `.carousel-inner`, however the html structure is a bit different from yours, you can adjust it to fit your requirements.

```
.carousel-inner{
    height: 550px;
}
```

With only adjusting the height of the carousel may cause your images to be squashed, so I quite recommend to customize the responsiveness of your carousel using media queries (according to Bootstrap's documentation):

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Hope that the answer can help you!

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add below line in your css

```
.bx-wrapper img{height: 550px; background-position: center; background-size: cover;}
```

Hope its working :)